# What is the proper name for the corkscrew at the top of a soda bottle?

Tags: single-word-requests

At the top of a bottle of pop, there is a corkscrew pattern into which the plastic cap is twisted, tightened and sealed.

What is the name of this feature of the bottle?

Comment: Can you add the results of your own research to your question?

Comment: It's called the _top_.

Comment: In Thai we call it "spiral".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on exactly what part of the bottle top you mean. If you mean the top part of the bottle having a spiraling bit on it, that is called the *finish*, specifically an *external threaded* finish. If you mean just the spiraling thread itself, that is called the *external thread*.

[image: images of seven examples of threaded bottle tops]

There are two parts to a bottle seal: the *finish* and the *closure*. The *closure* is the sealing device; the *finish* (also called the *neck finish*) is the part of the bottle that accepts the closure. On a screwtop bottle, the finish’s *external thread* fits to the cap’s matching *internal thread*.

There are many other types of finish to accept other closures such as the familiar stoppers (corks), crown caps, etc.

Supporting facts, references, and specific expertise:

1. http://www.sks-bottle.com/CapNeck.html
2. http://www.sha.org/bottle/finishes.htm
3. I buy bottles and caps for a manufacturing business.

Answer (score 7):

It's the same feature that's on screws and bolts, [a thread](http://www.sha.org/bottle/closures.htm#Threaded%20Closures).

Comment: Can you provide a source?

Comment: Here you go http://www.sha.org/bottle/closures.htm#Threaded Closures   I give up trying to fix the link...just scroll down to threaded closures in the index of this linked page.

Comment: @Chris, please edit the link into your answer instead of adding it via a comment.  Make the answer complete enough to stand on its own; then delete extraneous comments.